# Selecting by two fields in UNION ALL and ordering between rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a small problem I have a MySQL Table called categories that looks like so:

```
| id | parent_id | name | position | status | ... |
| 1  |    0      |  A   |     1    |    1   | ... |
| 2  |    1      |  A1  |     2    |    1   | ... |
| 3  |    2      |  A2  |     1    |    1   | ... |
| 4  |    1      |  A3  |     1    |    1   | ... |
| 5  |    0      |  B   |     2    |    1   | ... |
```

Basically a table that holds all my categories with multi level depth, each category that is a  sub category has a `parent_id > 0`. At any given time I am using the following SQL statement to only select the top level categories that have `parent_id = 0` and their first level children that have parent_id = id of category with parent_id = 0.

```
SELECT * FROM categories WHERE parent_id = 0 UNION ALL SELECT c.* FROM categories c
INNER JOIN categories p ON c.parent_id = p.id WHERE p.parent_id
```

**1. Problem**

This will always select all categories even if they have `status = 0` which is a problem. So I tried adding `AND status = 1` to both `WHERE` statements however I this does not work as all categories get selected regardless of status.

Second thing I tried is since on first select I'm only selecting categories with `parent_id =  0` and then making a UNION with all categories where parent_id matches id's of those from the first select I could just add `AND status = 0` to only the first `SELECT WHERE` and then the parent category that has status 0 would not get selected and thus when UNION is made it's children would also not get selected. However if I just add `AND status = 1` to the first `WHERE` then I only get the categories with `parent_id & status = 1` and nothing happens in the UNION.

**2. Problem**
Once I do this select I would have to order the categories and subcategories by the position value this can be done in PHP using the sort functions but this is pretty expansive when you have some 8000 categories.

I tried adding `ORDER BY id ASC, position ASC`. After my last `WHERE` statement I would like it so that I would get an output like so:

```
| id  | parent_id | position |
|  1  |    0      |     1    |
|  3  |    1      |     1    |
|  6  |    1      |     2    |
|  2  |    0      |     2    |
|  4  |    2      |     1    |
```

Or even:

```
| id  | parent_id | position |
|  1  |    0      |     1    |
|  2  |    0      |     2    |
|  3  |    1      |     1    |
|  6  |    1      |     2    |
|  4  |    2      |     1    |
```

I thot that second example would be pretty trivial and I got it to work when my statement did not include UNION ALL. But with the UNION my statement just like with the status = 1 returns only parent categories.

```
SELECT * FROM categories WHERE parent_id = 0 UNION ALL SELECT c.* FROM categories c
INNER JOIN categories p ON c.parent_id = p.id WHERE p.parent_id ORDER BY parent_id ASC, position ASC;
```

Since all parents have parent_id = 0 they would be listed first however ordered by position and then all children would be ordered together by parent_id first and then by position.

Comment: Can you create [an sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have understood correctly, I think you want the following:

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.* FROM categories c, categories p
WHERE c.status<>0 and (c.parent_id = 0 OR (c.parent_id=p.id and p.parent_id=0))
ORDER BY c.id,c.position
```

Comment: Something like that but this selects all categories multiple times.